# Double Enchant - Second enchantment don't work (soul trap)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just got the "Extra Effect" perk and enchanted my one-handed axe with Health Absorb+Soul Trap, but the Soul Trap is not working. After killing enemies i don't trap the soul on the gem. Is this a bug? It's possible to have the soul trap as second enchantment?

Comment: Do you have empty soul gems available, large enough to fit the soul?

Comment: How many seconds of Soul Trap does it have? Paired with a damage-over-time enchant you have to be careful that the ongoing damage doesn't kill the target after the Soul Trap timer has run out.

Answer (score 3):

Soul Trap works just fine as an enchantment, single or double.  One of my two daggers had a very similar set of enchantments.  (I think I had one with Fire/Soul Trap as well) There's a couple of reasons why this might not work properly, though:

- Do you have empty soul gems?  You've got to have gems in your inventory large enough to trap the soul.  There's usually a warning about this when you make the kill if you're missing a gem.
- Does your weapon have charges?  Especially with a double enchantment, you don't get very many swings before the weapon needs recharging.
- Did the enemy resist soul trap?  It's a status debuff, so sometimes the enemy resists the spell.
- Is it something you summoned?  It's not possible to soul trap a creature you summoned.

Comment: I filled all the above (a lot of soul gems of diferent types, charged weapon, non-resistance non-summoned enemy). I enchanted the weapon in whiterun, got out and killed one sabre-cat and it didn't trap his/it soul. I'll try again to see if it was only a one-time bug.